# I am facing this error in SQL Server - "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, logic

I am trying to run the below query, but I am encountering this error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

```
SELECT 
        IVCSUM1.ivcnum "Invoice Number"
        ,IVCSUM1.ivcgrsamt_amt "Gross Amount"
        ,IVCSUM1.ivcgrsamt_cur "Gross Amount Currency"
        ,SUM(ISNULL(IVCLINE1.ivclinextamt_amt, 0) 
            + ISNULL((SELECT SUM(TaxAmount_amt) FROM MC_INVTAX WHERE ivclinref_oi = IVCLINE1.ivlnoi), 0) 
            + ISNULL((SELECT SUM(amtchg_amt) FROM MC_INVCHG INVCHG1 WHERE IVCLINE1.ivlnoi = ivclinref_oi), 0)) "Invoice Line Amount"
    FROM
        MC_IVCSUM IVCSUM1 LEFT JOIN
        MC_IVCLINE IVCLINE1 on IVCSUM1.ivsmoi = IVCLINE1.invsumm_oi
    GROUP BY ivsmoi, ivcnum,IVCSUM1.ivcgrsamt_amt, IVCSUM1.ivcgrsamt_cur
```

I cannot join the tables *MC_INVCHG* and *MC_INVTAX* to the main query because it's causing duplicates in the *IVCLINE1.ivclinextamt_amt* field and the sum ends up being wrong.

Below is sample data I have pulled from the tables by joining them.

| Invoice Number | Line | Gross Amount | Tax amount | Change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00 0001180 7 DEC03 | 1 | 80 | -5.04 | NULL |
| 00 0001180 7 DEC03 | 1 | 80 | 5.04 | NULL |
| 00 0001180 7 DEC03 | 2 | 40 | 2 | NULL |

What I am trying to accomplish with the query is, Invoice Line Amount = (80 + (5.04 + (-5.04)) + 0) + (40 + 2 + 0)

Since change is NULL for this, it is being considered as 0.

Is there a way to accomplish this in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good place to use `CROSS APPLY` as it allows you to calculate a value and then use it, without the constraints you've run into.

```
SELECT 
    IVCSUM1.ivcnum [Invoice Number]
    , IVCSUM1.ivcgrsamt_amt [Gross Amount]
    , IVCSUM1.ivcgrsamt_cur [Gross Amount Currency]
    , SUM(ISNULL(IVCLINE1.ivclinextamt_amt, 0) 
        + ISNULL(S1.TaxAmount_amt_Total, 0) 
        + ISNULL(S2.amtchg_amt_Total, 0)) [Invoice Line Amount]
FROM MC_IVCSUM IVCSUM1
LEFT JOIN MC_IVCLINE IVCLINE1 on IVCSUM1.ivsmoi = IVCLINE1.invsumm_oi
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT SUM(TaxAmount_amt) TaxAmount_amt_Total
  FROM MC_INVTAX
  WHERE ivclinref_oi = IVCLINE1.ivlnoi
) S1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(amtchg_amt) amtchg_amt_Total
    FROM MC_INVCHG INVCHG1
    WHERE IVCLINE1.ivlnoi = ivclinref_oi
) S2
GROUP BY ivsmoi, ivcnum, IVCSUM1.ivcgrsamt_amt, IVCSUM1.ivcgrsamt_cur;
```

Note square brackets, `[]`, are the best practice way to escape object names.